# How to enable fifth serial port on Debian 7

Tags: debian, serial-port

I have put a fresh install of Debian 7.9.0 on an ASRock IMB-150 mainboard and only 4 of the 5 on-board serial ports seem to be enabled.

```
root@myhost:~# dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    1.476855] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.497885] serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    1.518912] serial8250: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.539944] serial8250: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    1.561202] 00:07: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.604531] 00:08: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    1.648446] 00:09: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 7) is a 16550A
[    1.688367] 00:0a: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 7) is a 16550A
root@myhost:~#
```

I also installed setserial and get this information from it:

```
root@myhost:/# setserial -g /dev/ttyS*
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 7
/dev/ttyS3, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 7
root@myhost:/#
```

I undersatand this is because Debian 7 only detects a maximum of four ports by default.  I have followed the instructions I found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1753958), editing the grub file but this seems to have had no effect.  Perhaps these instructions apply to a different version of Debian or Ubuntu only.

Can anyone tell me how to enable the fifth serial port?

Thanks.